# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0:

Tags: android

I am just getting the below error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.csc.navigationdrawer/com.example.csc.navigationdrawer.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML
>   file line #0: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

```
package com.example.csc.navigationdrawer;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{//,TransactionFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView nvDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

Menu menu;
TextView _headerTextView;
ProgressBar _progressBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Set a Toolbar to replsace the ActionBar.
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


// Find our drawer view
mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
// Find our drawer view
nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
// Setup drawer view
setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

//        nvDrawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_AccountTransfer_fragment).setVisible(false);
//        nvDrawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_WebsurferTransfer_fragment).setVisible(false);
//        getAllowedTransfer();


// get the main fragment
menu = nvDrawer.getMenu();
MenuItem bedMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_Home_fragment);
selectDrawerItem(bedMenuItem);


}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
drawerToggle.syncState();
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
// Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
// NOTE: Make sure you pass in a valid toolbar reference.  ActionBarDrawToggle() does not require it
// and will not render the hamburger icon without it.
return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                return true;
            }
        });
}
public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
// Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
Fragment fragment = null;
Class fragmentClass;
switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.nav_Home_fragment:
        fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        break;
    case R.id.nav_Transaction_fragment:
        fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        break;
//            case R.id.nav_AccountTransfer_fragment:
//                fragmentClass = TransactionFragment.class;
//                break;
//            case R.id.nav_WebsurferTransfer_fragment:
//                fragmentClass = WebSurferFragment.class;
//                break;
//            case R.id.nav_Setting_fragment:
//                fragmentClass = TransactionFragment.class;
//                break;
//            case R.id.nav_Logout_fragment:
//                CommonFunctions.logout(MainActivity.this);
//                return;

    default:
        fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
}

try {
    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

// Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
menuItem.setChecked(true);
// Set action bar title
setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
// Close the navigation drawer
mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
// mCompositeDisposable.clear();
}





}
```

and for the home fragment

```
package com.example.csc.navigationdrawer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

   // private CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable;

   // private DatabaseHandler db;


    View view;


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }


        //get the details from internal database
      /*  mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

        db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());*/


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false);








     /*   _cardView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw()  {

                _cardView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                minHeight = _cardView.getHeight();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = _cardView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = minHeight;
                _cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                return true;
            }
        });
*/




        return view;
    }





    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       // mCompositeDisposable.clear();
    }


    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
      public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }




}
```

Comment: Please post the code for files fragment_home.xml and also the build.gradle under the app directory I suspect the problem is coming form here.

Comment: Can you please search by cntrl+f if toolbar,drawer_layout,nvView contains in your R.layout.activity_main?Maybe you changed on of that view's id in xml and didn't change in code.

Comment: solved in my xml inversion used in appcompat thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML file has some errors. please post your xml file also.